# How can I make this exact figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: residual network] I want to make this tikz picture but finding problem making these node filling black, the middle dotted line and also want to smaller the size of number on arrows.

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
  %usepackage{algorithm}
  \usepackage{pifont}
  \title{test}
  \author{xyz}
  \date{June 2022}

  \begin{document}

   \maketitle

  \section{Introduction}
  \begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[mycircle/.style={circle,draw=black, text opacity=1, inner sep=5pt}, myarrow/.style={-Stealth, font=\smaller},node distance=0.6cm and 1.2cm]
  \node[mycircle] (c1) {$s$};
  \node[mycircle,below right=of c1] (c2) {$v_2$};
  \node[mycircle,right=of c2] (c3) {$v_4$};
  \node[mycircle,above right=of c1] (c4) {$v_1$};
  \node[mycircle,right=of c4] (c5) {$v_3$};
  \node[mycircle,below right=of c5] (c6) {$t$};
 \foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p in {% start node/end node/text/position
       c1/c2/7:\textcolor{blue}{4}/below,
  c1/c4/8:\textcolor{blue}{5}/above,
  c2/c3/6:\textcolor{blue}{5}/below,
  c3/c6/2:\textcolor{blue}{2}/below,
  c4/c5/6:\textcolor{blue}{6}/above,
  c5/c6/10:\textcolor{blue}{7}/above,
  c5/c2/9:\textcolor{blue}{2}/below,
  c3/c5/5:\textcolor{blue}{3}/below,
  c2.70/c4.290/2:\textcolor{blue}{1}/below}
   \draw [myarrow] (\i) -- node[sloped,font=\small,\p] {\txt} (\j);



\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A cut $(S,T)$ in flow network, where $S=(s,v_1.v_2)$ and $T (v_3,v_4,t)$ with net flow across $(S,T)$ is $f(S,T)=9$ and thecapacity $c(S,T)=12$.}
 \end{figure}    



 \end{document}
```

Note: Numbers in the code are changed due to my requirement.

Comment: Dumping a picture and asking people to reproduce it from scratch isn't allowed. Please show some work that you tried and people will take it from here.

Comment: Just a starting point: try the `tkz-graph` package.

Comment: @Miyase, yes you are absolutely right, i forgot to add that please see my edited version of the post :)

Comment: One last nitpick: on this site, it's also required to provide *full* LaTeX code, something called a Minimal Working Example. This is out of respect for the people willing to help, so that they can copy-paste your code and test it. Also, without it it's impossible to know which packages (related to the question) you're using.

Comment: Another example: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/prims-algorithm/

Comment: @Miyase, yes right i re-edit the post.

Comment: You should take a look at `tikz-cd` and at the `circledsteps` package, which is based on tikz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, using your current code. Positions set manually can be calculated by some lower-level functions from `tikz`. Some minor fine-tuning might still be needed, like e.g. using the Stealth tip inside `\graph`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    [mycircle/.style={circle,draw=black,
     text opacity=1, inner sep=5pt}, 
     myarrow/.style={-Stealth, font=\tiny},% <<< or \small
     node distance=0.6cm and 1.2cm,
     blk/.style={fill=black, text=white}]% <<< black & white
  \node[mycircle, blk]                      (c1) {$s$};
  \node[mycircle,below right=of c1, blk]    (c2) {$v_2$};
  \node[mycircle,right=of c2]               (c3) {$v_4$};
  \node[mycircle,above right=of c1, blk]    (c4) {$v_1$};
  \node[mycircle,right=of c4]               (c5) {$v_3$};
  \node[mycircle,below right=of c5]         (c6) {$t$};

 \foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p in {% start node/end node/text/position
    c1/c2/7:\textcolor{blue}{4}/below,
    c1/c4/8:\textcolor{blue}{5}/above,
    c2/c3/6:\textcolor{blue}{5}/below,
    c3/c6/2:\textcolor{blue}{2}/below,
    c4/c5/6:\textcolor{blue}{6}/above,
    c5/c6/10:\textcolor{blue}{7}/above,
    c5/c2/9:\textcolor{blue}{2}/below,
    c3/c5/5:\textcolor{blue}{3}/below,
    c2.70/c4.290/2:\textcolor{blue}{1}/below}
   \draw [myarrow] (\i) -- node[sloped,\p] {\txt} (\j);

% ~~~ new: introducing some dummy-nodes ~~~~
  \node (dum1) [below] at (2.82,-2.1) {S T};% can be calculated
  \node (dum2) [below] at (2.82, 2) {};
  \node (dum3) [below=of c3]    {};
  \node (dum4) [below=of c2]    {};

  \draw [dashed]  (dum1.south) -- (dum2);% <<< dashed vertical
  
  \graph{% arrows
     (dum1) -> {(dum3), (dum4)};
    };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```